# Disassociate value of Date method from the object

Tags: javascript, string, date

I need to be able to do something like this

```
var date = new Date();
var month = date.getDate();
var strmonth = month.toString(); //This returns [Window Object]
```

I've also tried this variation

```
month = Number(date.getDate());
strmonth = month.toString(); // This also returns [Window Object]
```

Comment: None of those should return the window, in any browser, so you're doing something really strange here.

Comment: Not sure what browser you are getting that is returning [Window Object]

Comment: getDate() returns day not month.

Comment: *getDate* returns a Number, so `Number(getDate())` returns exactly the same value as `getDate()`. [*Number.prototype.toString*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.7.4.2) returns a string, not the window (global) object.

Answer (score 0):

You may be trying to get the month name from *date.getMonth*. You can use the month number returned by *getMonth* with an array of month names, e.g.

```
function getMonth(date) {
  var months = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun',
                'Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];
  return months[date.getMonth()];
}

console.log(getMonth(new Date()));
```

You can replace the month names with whatever suits. If you really want, you can extend the built–in Date object with a *getMonthName* method:

```
Date.prototype.getMonthName = function() {
  return ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'][this.getMonth()];
}

console.log(new Date().getMonthName());
```